# What is the name of this function declaration syntax only working in JScript (IE)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jscript

I recently came upon this code on the web :

```
function window::onload() {
    alert('onload!');
}
```

This (strange) syntax is only working in Internet Explorer (IE 8 in my case) and I wasn't sure of how it was called so I could search for it.

I simply want to know if there is some documentation related to this type of functions and if so, how are they called ?

Comment: causes an error in IE for me...

Comment: This is not legal javascript.

Comment: I know, but IE 8 recognizes it as valid JScript and executes the alert on onload.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it's an IE-specific extension that allows you to define certain types of event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is automatic event binding in JScript, similar to the `Object_EventName` naming convention in VBScript.

See: [Scripting Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx)

Supposedly it has meen removed in later version of Internet Explorer, just as some other rarely used non-standard features.

Comment: it's not that it was removed per se, it's that IE switched from jScript to javascript...

Comment: @dandavis: Do you have any reference for that? I have never heard of such a switch, and from what I can find it still uses the Chakra JScript engine in the latest version; IE 11.

Comment: JScript is just a name. i probably should have said ECMAScript since we are discussing semantics. If anyone is not allowed to say "JavaScript", it's M$. The important change is ES5 compliance, which IE never sought or achieved with ES3 and prior versions of JScript. Gaining the inter-operable ES5 compliance means that proprietary JScript-only syntax will not work... I didn't mean to imply they struck a deal with Sun.

Answer (score 0):

MS-ES5EX ECMAScript extension for Event Handler Function Definitions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955429.aspx